# Has a human baby's heart started beating only 18 days after conception?

Tags: biology, physiology, abortion

I saw billboards like this driving around Florida:

> [image: Billboard image]
>
> 18 Days from conception my HEART was beating
> [...] Prolife Across America

Is this true?

Comment: What a horrendous typesetting.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The fetal heart may begin to beat at approximately the 22nd day after fertilization which corresponds to 3 weeks and 1 day after [fertilization](http://www.ehd.org/dev_article_unit4.php#fb1) i.e. 5 weeks 1 day of [pregnancy](http://www.ehd.org/prenatal-summary.php).  Between 5 ½ to 6 ½ weeks based on the last menstrual period, a fetal pole or a fetal heartbeat may be detected by vaginal [ultrasound](http://radiopaedia.org/articles/fetal-heart-beat).

> Angiogenic cell clusters are the building blocks of what will become a fetal heart tube known as the primitive heart [tube](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1767864/). The primitive heart tube develops around three to four weeks and goes through an incredible transformation transforming into a four-chamber heart.

Comment: 3 weeks 1 day after conception is 5 weeks 1 day of pregnancy, by the way. Pregnancy dating is weird ;-) (just so the OP can relate the two dates in your answer)

Comment: @YviDe-Thanks and I will add this information in the answer!